# Hashset + thread pool of callable

Tags: коллекции, java, concurrency

Добрый день!

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);
HashSet<Future<Double>> callableSet = new HashSet<Future<Double>>(n);

        for(;n>0;n--)
    {
        Double middleArgument = step/2.0 + step*(n-1);          
        callableSet.add( executor.submit( new rectangleMethodStep( middleArgument , step) ) );
    }
```

В данном коде, **rectangleMethodStep** - **Callable**, который вычисляет некоторое значение. Всякий раз как я читаю из **HashSet** , я получаю ту же последовательность, с разным порядком. Исходя из специфики этой коллекции, я не понимаю почему порядок всегда меняется?

Ведь порядок у нас определяется хэш-кодом элемента, значит порядок должен быть постоянным

Comment: если hashcode не переопределён, то он меняется между запусками если чо.

Comment: Читаем [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

>  It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

То есть порядок итерации по набору элементов вам никто не гарантирует.

Comment: @voipp, Это вы сейчас описали как происходит вычисление индекса корзины в хэшмэпе по хэшу. 

А вот, что можно прочитать про сам хэшкод:

    /* As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by
     * class {@code Object} does return distinct integers for distinct
     * objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal
     * address of the object into an integer, but this implementation
     * technique is not required by the
     * Java programming language.)
     */

А адрес объекта между запусками - величина непостоянная.

Comment: @voipp: Исходники — не источник, конкретная реализация может меняться с каждым апдейтом или там при смене фаз луны. Гарантировано только то, что обещает документация. Документация — вот единственный правильный источник.

Comment: а объясните, почему хэш-код учитывает системное время, настройки компьютера, фазу луны ?

Comment: Что вам непонятно в фразе "This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer" ?

Comment: Хех, я начал писать предыдущий комментарий, когда закончил, @Nofate уже запостил свой комментарий! Теперь я не понимаю строчку : **but this implementation
 * technique is not required by the
 * Java programming language**  Что значит не требуется?

Comment: @voipp: Это объясняющий пример для читателя. Любая имплементация может пользоваться принципом «hashcode == адрес», может не пользоваться, как и когда ей хочется. Гарантировано лишь, что у равных объектов хешкоды совпадают.

Comment: Ну то есть хэш объекта не обязан реализовываться именно так, в разных реализациях языка это может меняться и на это знание лучше не полагаться и не зависеть от него.

Важно только то, что в течение одного запуска хэш одного и того же объекта не может меняться.